# Does Interface Builder use the -init method to initialize view controllers?

Tags: cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I have setup tab bar controller using interface builder, and each tab bar item is linked to a view controller (4 tabs, 4 view controllers). I want to know if Interface Builder uses an `-init` method to initialize the view controller because apparently this method does not get called:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil;
```

... and I want to do some initializations. I can't add that to `-viewDidLoad` since it is recalled in case of memory warning. Any idea?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Objects loaded from a `*.(nib|xib)` are inited with:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)inCoder;
```

So you could override that or if doing your setup after `-initWithCoder:` is called is not a problem you could use:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib;
```

from the NSNibAwaking protocol.

Answer (score 10):

I was also going to mention `initWithCoder` vs `awakeFromNib`.

In general, I override `initWithCoder` when allocating memory for the object or setting values.  When you need to do some setup after the IBOutlets are connected, then override `awakeFromNib`. Until then, IBOutlet instance variables to other views and controls are not connected.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you want to implement `-(void) awakeFromNib`.

[NSNibAwaking Protocol Reference (requires ADC login)](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSNibAwaking_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)