# initWithFrame not executing in UIVIew

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have made a `UIView` subclass & want to execute a method on `initWithFrame:`, but this method is not being called.

When I call the method from `initWithCoder:`, which is executing, the code crashes showing this error:

> **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initialization coder method:'**

My code is:

```
-(void)initialize
{
    //code
}

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self initialize];

        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{ 
    self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];

    if(self)
    {
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: calling virtual method in constructor (-(void)initialize) is not good practice, because it can be overridden in subclass. You can use c function instead of initialize method

Comment: Shouldn't initWithCoder "return self;"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you specify this UIView inside IB or storyBoard so initWithCoder is called.
Delete initWithCoder and use awakeFromNib

```
    - (void)awakeFromNib{
    //custom init code
   [self initialize];
    }
```

Comment: it is not necessary, both of them called when View is specified with IB and Nib, at first initWithCoder: and at second awakeFromNib: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492106/does-interface-builder-use-the-init-method-to-initialize-view-controllers

Comment: Thanks! awakeFromNib call after initWithCoder(encode XIB file), so it's safety for custom method.

Comment: yes, the problem is that before calling awakeFromNib all IBOutlets and View created with IB are nil pointers, so you can't use them in initWithCoder:, you should do it after awakeFromNib:

Comment: For completeness, still need to return self in initWithCoder.

Answer (score 6):

You're not returning `self` from your `initWithCoder:` method.

Comment: if i am returning self from initWithCoder: the code is executing but din't get any change in content called in  initialize: method

Comment: @anupam, are you sure? did you set break point in - initialize method to ensure that? it seems like you using code related on UIView subViews in initialize method, at moment when calling initWithCoder, properties to them are nil pointers. They will be initializeed only after awakeFromNib

Comment: @PavelKatunin you are probably right, though we can't see the initialize method so who knows?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
    { 
        self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];

        if(self)
        {

        }
    return self;
    }
```