# Set object (added via Interface Builder) property before it loads?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, interface-builder

I've added a custom UIView in Interface Builder and an outlet to my view controller, and I want to set some conditional properties before the view loads. How should I do this?

I tried setting the properties in these methods:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
```

Gets called **before** the UIView initialiser, however, the outlet in the view controller logs `(null)` at this point.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

At this point the outlet already points to my UIView, but this method is called **after** the UIView initialiser.

I could write a custom initialiser for the UIView, but how would I call that initialiser from my viewController before (instead of?) Interface Builder initialises it?

Comment: What's the sequence of events in loading the view? Are you loading it programmaticly from the viewController? What are the conditional properties?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Interface Builder use the -init method to initialize view controllers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492106/does-interface-builder-use-the-init-method-to-initialize-view-controllers)

Comment: @Anna, all my views are added via Interface Builder, but I want to apply a different colour to my custom UIView based on a check that I want to do in my view controller

Comment: @jlehr, this is not a duplicate because the answers in the other question do not answer mine - they all suggest to override initialisation of the UIView, but I DON'T want my views to do the job of my view controller, hence my question

Comment: @artooras You might want to reread it. Actually, the question is about view controllers, and the answers are general, since the nib loading facilities work the same way for instances of all classes that adopt the `NSCoding` protocol.

Comment: @jlehr, please see the discussion under Droppy's answer, you'll see what tangent we have taken, which is different from your quoted question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you do this kind of setup in your view's layoutSubviews method.

Here's the sequence of events:

- ViewController loads the view; view initializes
- In the ViewController's viewWillLayoutSubviews method, set the view property
- In the view's layoutSubviews method, the view can update itself based on the value of the property

If that sequence of events doesn't match the timing of what you're doing, you can also try calling setNeedsDisplay on the view after you are able to update the property. This causes the view's layoutSubviews method to be called on the next display cycle.

Comment: That's definitely an option, but I wanted to avoid the `view` to have to draw itself twice, hence my question about a possibility to set a property **before** the `view` gets initialised. I can do this by writing a custom initialiser for the `view` if I were to initialise the `view` in the `viewController`. But my question is - can I do the same if the `view` is added via Interface Builder?

Comment: I think the first time the view draws is after layoutSubviews. You could test it by adding a log message to the view's drawRect method.

Comment: Thanks @Anna, your answer is correct. I was doing my `view` customisation in my `view`'s `init` method which gets called before `viewDidLoad` in my `viewController`. Instead, when I moved my styling to `drawRect` or `layoutSubviews` methods of the `view', both of which get called **after** the `viewDidLoad` of the `viewController`, everything works fine

Comment: Great! Thanks for confirming that.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably override the `awakeFromNib` method to do this.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html):

> 4. It sends an `awakeFromNib` message to the appropriate objects in the nib file that define the matching selector:
>
>    - In OS X, this message is  sent to any interface objects that define the method. It is also sent
>        to the File’s Owner and any placeholder objects that define it as
>        well.
>    - In iOS, this message is sent only to the interface objects that
>        were instantiated by the nib-loading code. It is not sent to File’s
>        Owner, First Responder, or any other placeholder objects.

Comment: You mean `awakeFromNib` method for the UIView? Because I want to handle the conditional logic of setting properties to views in my view controller

Comment: @artooras In your *overridden* `UIView` class, yes.  Or possibly in the *overridden* `UIViewController` class...

Comment: Hm... my `UIViewController` is initiated with `initWithNibName` by another `viewController` before it is pushed onto the navigation stack. I just tested, and in this case `awakeFromNib` is not called on `UIViewController`...